# Update cedet in emacs on Mac

Tags: macos, emacs, cedet

I installed emacs using Home Brew but later I found the cedet bundled with emacs is out dated. 
But when I followed the instructions in cedet official site, downloaded the tar file, un-tar it and run make in that dir, then I got 2 errors telling me ssomething is wrong with eieio... The version I want to install is cedet1.1...
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just update emacs to the newest version using homebrew, which should be 24.5.1. The cedet bundled with it is V2.0, which is the same as sf.